# Simple way to draw a triangle with one side and two angles given

Tags: tikz-pgf

What's the simplest way to draw an triangle (not as a node!) with tikz with a given side and two given angles?

Comment: Interesting, but how about the orientation of triangle in the plane? Should we assume the given edge is parallel to page borders?

Comment: I think you may assume this, because one can easily rotate the result via scope...

Comment: Two or three angles? :)

Comment: @percusse, obviously two would suffice. [edit: oops! didn't see the `:)` face at the end of your comment...]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got an example by googling [*Solving ASA triangles*](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-asa-triangles.html) .

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Given
\def\myside{9}
\def\myanga{76}
\def\myangb{34}
%===============
\draw (0,0) -- (0:\myside)
     let \n1={(180-(\myanga+\myangb))},
         \n2={(\myside*(sin(\myanga)/sin(\n1))} in
     -- (\myangb:\n2) -- cycle node{\n1,\n2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn you're faster than superman :)

Answer (score 6):

Not as simple as percusse's answer but easy to understand.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, angles, quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw coordinate[label=below:a] (a) --++(0:4cm) coordinate[label=below:b] (b);

\path[name path=ac] (a)--++(30:3cm);
\path[name path=bc] (b)--++(180-37:3cm);

\path [name intersections={of = ac and bc, by=c}];

\node[above] at (c) {c};

\draw[use as bounding box] (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle%
     pic[draw, "$30^\circ$", angle eccentricity=1.6] {angle=b--a--c}
    pic[draw, "$37^\circ$", angle eccentricity=1.6] {angle=c--b--a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is too long as a comment but too short for typing exercise.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\newpsstyle{nolabel}{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(8,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-90]{A}(8,0){B}
    \pstRotation[style=nolabel,RotAngle=30]{A}{B}
    \pstRotation[style=nolabel,RotAngle=-37]{B}{A}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=90]{A}{B'}{B}{A'}{C}
    \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
    \psset{MarkAngleRadius=1.5}
    \pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{C}{$30^\circ$}
    \pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{A}{$37^\circ$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]