# if i draw something using stand alone, how do i label the drawing (angles, sides,coordinates, etc.)

Tags: standalone

If I draw a triangle in stand alone, how do I label my drawing? I am able to draw my picture but I cant label any of the angles or sides.

Comment: And which code exactly are you using? How are you drawing your image? Please add a complete, minimal version of the document showing the relevant settings.

Comment: Why would standalone make a difference? Does it work when you don't compile it with standalone?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173270/19356 should help you.

Answer (score 2):

With `angles` library, it is easy.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- node[midway,below]{A} (5,0) coordinate (B)
        -- node[midway,right]{B} (2.5,5) coordinate (C) -- node[midway,left]{C} (A)
     pic [fill=olive!50] {angle = A--B--C}
     pic [draw,<-,red,thick,angle radius=5mm] {angle = C--B--A}
     pic [draw,<-,red,thick,angle radius=5mm] {angle = B--A--C}
     pic [draw,<-,red,thick,angle radius=5mm] {angle = A--C--B};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear what your question is.  But, I am guessing that you want to alter the a diagram in the main text that is done as a `standalone` diagram.  If that is the case, you could make use of `\providecommand` and `.provide style` (as per the link in the References below) to define the `standalone` diagram.

The MWE below consists of three files:

1. `MyPreamble.sty` which contains the preamble for both the main file and the `standalone` figure.
2. `MyTriangle.tex` which is the standalone figure.
3. The main .tex file which `\input`s `MyTriangle.tex` three times with altered the settings.

The first figure is the default figure, the second shows a case where you don't want *any* text labels, and the third shows how to change the labels. Also illustrated is how to change the style of the figure:

[image]

### References:

- [Is there something like \providetikzstyle similar to \providecommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/is-there-something-like-providetikzstyle-similar-to-providecommand)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{MyPreamble.sty}
    \usepackage{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/is-there-something-like-providetikzstyle-similar-to-providecommand
    \tikzset{/handlers/.provide style/.code={%
        \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{}%
            {\pgfkeys {\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeysalso {#1}}}%
    }}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{MyTriangle.tex}
    \documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{MyPreamble}
    
    \begin{document}
    \providecommand*{\SideALabel}{$A$}%
    \providecommand*{\SideBLabel}{$B$}%
    \providecommand*{\SideCLabel}{$C$}%
    
    \tikzset{My Line Style/.provide style={thick, black}}
    \tikzset{My Node Style/.provide style={}}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw [My Line Style] (0,0) coordinate (A) 
            -- node[midway,below, My Node Style] {\SideALabel} (5,0)   coordinate (B)
            -- node[midway,right, My Node Style] {\SideBLabel} (2.5,5) coordinate (C) 
            -- node[midway,left,  My Node Style] {\SideCLabel} (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}



\usepackage{MyPreamble}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \input{MyTriangle.tex}%
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \tikzset{My Line Style/.provide style={ultra thick, draw=blue, fill=yellow}}
    \tikzset{My Node Style/.provide style={text=white}}
    \input{MyTriangle.tex}%
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \newcommand*{\SideALabel}{$X$}%
    \newcommand*{\SideBLabel}{$Y$}%
    \newcommand*{\SideCLabel}{$Z$}%
    \tikzset{My Line Style/.provide style={ultra thick, draw=none, fill=green}}
    \tikzset{My Node Style/.provide style={text=red}}
    \input{MyTriangle.tex}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```