# Is there a straight-forward way to measure angles in tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I'm aware of the `pgf` macros:

```
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints
```

and

```
\pgfmathanglebetweenlines
```

What I'd like to know is whether there are any macros in `tkz-euclide` that more easily accomplish the same thing.

For example, if I have two coordinates `A` and `B`, to measure the angle of the line passing through these two points, I can write

```
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
\edef\aeABangle{\pgfmathresult}
```

It would be convenient if there were a macro in `tkz-euclide` that could do this in a manner like

```
\tkzAngleAlong(A,B)
```

and then have some mechanism to retrieve the value of the angle.

I barely have a reading knowledge of French.  It's passable enough that I can usually figure out what's in the manual to `tkz-euclide`, but it's not sufficient for me to *guess* key words to search on.  So, I apologize if this is already well documented.

I know I could write my own macro to do this.  I'd just like to not have to reinvent the wheel (even though it's a relatively simple wheel to recreate).

Comment: You can search for `\tkzFindAngle()` in the manual.

Comment: @percusse I always feel *so stupid* after such questions.  But thank you.  You got me to the correct location in the manual!!!  :-)

Comment: @percusse Perhaps you could post a solution about `\tkzFindAngle`, `\tkzFindSlopeAngle`, and `\tkzGetAngle`.  That way a web search will result in a quicker find.

Comment: @A.Ellett See also [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243525/4778). It's not actually about it, but I used them to find and print angles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you have:

1. `\tkzFindAngle(c,b,a)`
   The angle in the center is the one being found. Or in this case, the vertex `b`.
2. `\tkzGetAngle{angleCBA}`
   Gives the name to the angle.
3. `\FPround\angleCBA\angleCBA{0}`
   Rounds the angle to integers. The 0 indicates numbers after the decimal separator. I set one angle to have 10 of them as a demonstration.
4. `\tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](c,b,a)`
   Marks the angle with the arc. You can customize this using `draw`, `fill` and even `opacity`.
5. `\tkzLabelAngle[pos=-.82](c,b,a){\tiny $\angleCBA^\circ$}`
   Labels the angle. Pos indicates the position of the label, while the rest is similar to the syntax of a node. `(c,b,a)` indicates what angle/where the label should appear; and `$\angleCBA$` prints the angle.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{fp}

\tikzset{
    myangle/.style={fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black,size=.3,opacity=.3}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (5,3);
\coordinate (c) at (3,6);

\draw (a) coordinate[label=left:A] -- (b) coordinate[label=right:B] -- (c) coordinate[label=above:C] -- cycle;

\tkzFindAngle(c,b,a)\tkzGetAngle{angleCBA}\FPround\angleCBA\angleCBA{0}
\tkzFindAngle(a,c,b)\tkzGetAngle{angleACB}\FPround\angleACB\angleACB{10}
\tkzFindAngle(b,a,c)\tkzGetAngle{angleBAC}\FPround\angleBAC\angleBAC{0}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](c,b,a)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=-.82](c,b,a){\tiny $\angleCBA^\circ$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](a,c,b)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.6](a,c,b){\tiny $\angleACB^\circ$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](b,a,c)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=.7](b,a,c){\tiny $\angleBAC^\circ$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice work.

Comment: @A.Ellett I noticed a problem though (trying to fix it), but the angle B shouldn't be `-273`. It never happened to me. I'm looking into it.

Comment: I noticed that too, but I wasn't worried about that part.

Comment: Hi Alenanno, is it possible to use `\FPRound` with measuring arcs of circles? See e.g. this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542375/perfect-labels-for-minor-major-arcs-of-circle-using-tkz-euclide

Comment: Great answer! I tried with`\tikzset{myangle/.style={size=.5}}` and passing `\tkzMarkAngle[myangle](b,a,c)`, but that's giving an error. Tried adding units like `size=.5cm`, but that didn't work either. Should I not expect it to work? should I ask a new question? thanks!

Comment: Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/710071/tkz-euclide-set-style-of-angle-marks-globally