# Perfect labels for minor / major arcs of circle using Tkz-Euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, circles, tkz-euclide, arc

In Tkz-Euclide, is there a "built-in" (automatic) way to label the minor or major arc of a circle?

For instance, in the following circle, I would like to label the minor arc CD with measure 58 degrees (preferably without having to calculate and place a point or node in the perfect center of that arc!).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{gensymb} %for degree symbol
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\coordinate[label = above left:$A$] (A) at (130:3);
\coordinate[label = above right:$D$] (D) at (58:3);
\coordinate[label = right:$C$] (C) at (0:3);
\coordinate[label = left:$B$] (B) at (180:3);
\draw (B) -- (D) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (C);
\tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](E)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.60cm,%
opacity=.9](B,E,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.9](B,E,C){$126\degree$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9cm,%
opacity=.9](D,C,E)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1.3](D,C,E){$36\degree$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I know that one option is to create a new coordinate point and labeling it with `\coordinate[label = above right:$58\degree$] (F) at (29:3);` but this requires calculating the perfect center of that arc. Ideally, I would like a simple command like `\tkzLabelMinorArc[above right](D,C){$58\degree$}`.

I see on [this Tkz-Euclide cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/kpym/f08d1a326884e11dddb7d272359eb2bd) that Tkz-Euclide has similar commands for `\tkzLabelPoint`, `\tkzLabelAngle`, `\tkzLabelLine`, `\tkzLabelSegment`, and `\tkzLabelCircle`, but I cannot find a command to make perfect labels for Minor or Major Arcs of a circle. Does anyone know if this option exists in Tkz-Euclide?

**Edit**: Long time update to this question. Is it also possible to choose to locally (in specific cases, not the entire document) round the arc measure when desired, similar to how `\FPRound` works in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246611/48036)?

Comment: Sorry but the answer is no but it's not difficult to find a way to do this.

Comment: i've added a [pull request](https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-euclide/pull/4) with the lbpos option to set the relative position of the label

Comment: Is there any update on this? Is there now a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `\usetkzobj{all}`so you're not using the latest version of `tkz-euclide` which is 3.06. The solution below uses the last version.
It's possible with `tkz-euclide` but we need to create a new macro. You can get the middle of the arc with  `\tkzGetPoint{M}`. You can adapt the result, intros case you need to change

`\node[#1] at (tkzPointResult) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\tkz@An}\degree};`

It's possible to add some specific options if it's necessary.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\makeatletter

\def\tkzMarkArc{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@MarkArc}{\tkz@MarkArc[]}}   
\def\tkz@MarkArc[#1](#2,#3,#4){% 
\begingroup
\tkzCalcLength[cm](#4,#3) \tkzGetLength{tkz@len}
\tkzFindSlopeAngle(#4,#2)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@anga}
\tkzFindSlopeAngle(#4,#3)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@angb}
\tkzNormalizeAngle(\tkz@anga,\tkz@angb)
\edef\tkz@An{\fpeval{(\tkz@SecondAngle-\tkz@FirstAngle)}}
\edef\tkz@Angle{\fpeval{(\tkz@SecondAngle+\tkz@FirstAngle)/2}}
\tkzDefPoint(\tkz@Angle :\tkz@len){tkzPointResult}
\node[#1] at (tkzPointResult) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\tkz@An}\degree};
\endgroup 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{2}
\tkzDefPoint(30:\r){A}
\tkzDefPoint(85:\r){B}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)

\tkzMarkArc[above right](A,B,O)  \tkzGetPoint{M}

\tkzDrawPoints(B,A,M)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](O,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alain. I hope you consider building this macro into the next version of tkz-euclide.

Comment: @Mathemanic yes it's possible !

Comment: Hi Alain, thanks again! Is it possible to choose to locally round the arc measure (in specific cases, not the entire document), simlar to `\FPRound` in this answer? tex.stackexchange.com/a/246611/48036

Answer (score 2):

Didn't see anything in the manual, but you can define such a macro. Can't guarantee the example below works in all cases, though it seems to work fine here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{gensymb} %for degree symbol

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\LabelMinorArc[4][]{%
% optional arg: options for node
% mandatory args
%  - center coordinate
%  - first point circle
%  - second point on circle
\path let
\p1=(#2),\p2=(#3),\p3=(#4),
\n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},
\n2={atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)},
\n3={scalar(\n2-\n1)},
\n4={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}
in
(#2) ++(\n3/2+\n1:\n4) node[#1] {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\n3}\degree$};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\coordinate[label = above left:$A$] (A) at (130:3);
\coordinate[label = above right:$D$] (D) at (58:3);
\coordinate[label = right:$C$] (C) at (0:3);
\coordinate[label = left:$B$] (B) at (180:3);
\draw (B) -- (D) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (A) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (C);
\tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](E)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.60cm,%
opacity=.9](B,E,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.9](B,E,C){$126\degree$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.9cm,%
opacity=.9](D,C,E)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1.3](D,C,E){$36\degree$}

\LabelMinorArc[above right]{O}{C}{D}
\LabelMinorArc[above]{O}{D}{A}
\LabelMinorArc[left]{O}{A}{B}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the caveat about not defining the centre of the circle.